# When should one use asynchronous controller in asp.net mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, controller

Thus far worked with `asp.net mvc1` and just started with `asp.net mvc2`..... what are good candidates for executing a controller asynchronously? Should i use it for long running process or some background processing? What are the pros and cons choosing asynchronous controller in asp.net mvc 2? Any suggestion...

Comment: define your background processing.

Comment: @Shawn performing a bulkcopy inserting two lakhs records...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only use async if the operation is IO bound. A good example would be aggregating RSS feeds from multiple servers and then displaying them in a webpage.

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336138.aspx
- http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/04/05/improve-scalability-in-aspnet-mvc-using-asynchronous-requests/

for a good overview of asynchronous controllers.

And for more in-depth but non-MVC specific info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your controller's method is calling some other system for example query DB or external resources with HTTP and operation lasts long then you should implement those methods as `async` to let the thread used to doing that be released from waiting on the results and used to service other requests. Our application is getting threads from `ThreadPool` and number of them is limited. Considering that limitation and the situations of having lot of application users and also long-time queries for data is it very easy to see how important it is.